# Two possible definitions of composition of morphisms of ringed spaces. Are they equivalent?

Tags: sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

I'm trying to understand the definition of composition of morphisms of ringed spaces. I know there are several posts on MSE addressing this issue. But the specific issue I am going to discuss in the following isn't even mentioned of any of the posts I've looked at.

Given ringed spaces $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$, a morphism between them $(f,\psi^{\sharp}):(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is defined to be a pair $(f,\psi^{\sharp})$, where $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map of topological spaces and $\psi^{\sharp}:f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X$ is a morphism of sheaves over $X$ (i.e., $\psi^{\sharp}:f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X$ lives in the category $\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(X)$ of ring-valued sheaves over $X$), and where $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$ is the pullback of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Y$ on $Y$ along $f$, i.e., it is the sheafification of the presheaf $f_p\mathcal{O}_Y$ on $X$, where $f_p$ is defined [here on the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/008F). The data $(f,\psi^{\sharp})$ is equivalent to the data $(f,\psi^\flat)$, where $\psi^{\flat}:\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ lives in $\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Y)$. Here the morphisms $\psi^\sharp$ and $\psi^\flat$ are adjoint morphisms related by the adjunction of hom-sets
$$
\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(X)(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Y)(\mathcal{O}_Y, f_*\mathcal{O}_X).
$$

Now, considering the two different forms in which what can give a morphism of ringed spaces (in the form $(f,\psi^\sharp)$ or $(f,\psi^\flat)$), there are two different ways in which one can define the composition of morphisms of ringed spaces. Namely, if
$$
(g,\varphi^\sharp)\text{ or }(g,\varphi^\flat):(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\to(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)
$$
is another morphism of ringed spaces, we can define
$$
\begin{align}
(g,\varphi^\sharp)\circ(f,\psi^\sharp)&=(g\circ f,\psi^\sharp\circ f^{-1}\varphi^\sharp)\\
(g,\varphi^\flat)\circ(f,\psi^\flat)&=(g\circ f,g_*\psi^\flat\circ \varphi^\flat),
\end{align}
$$
where $f^{-1}$ denotes the pullback functor $f^{-1}:\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Y)\to\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(X)$ along $f$ and $g_*$ is the pushforward functor $g_*:\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Y)\to\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Z)$ along $g$. If one writes down the morphisms $\psi^\sharp$ and $\varphi^\sharp$ and tries to find some way to “compose them,” he/she will verify that this definition is the natural one. And analogously for $\psi^\flat$ and $\varphi^\flat$.

The next step would be showing that these two possible definitions of composition of morphisms are equivalent. This means, we should show that the morphism $\psi^\sharp\circ f^{-1}\varphi^\sharp$ of sheaves on $X$ and the morphism $g_*\psi^\flat\circ \varphi^\flat$ of sheaves on $Y$ are adjoint under the hom-set adjunction
$$
\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(X)((g\circ f)^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Z,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong\mathsf{Sh}_{\mathsf{Ring}}(Z)(\mathcal{O}_Z, (g\circ f)_*\mathcal{O}_X).
$$
(Where $(g\circ f)_*=g_*\circ f_*$ and $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ as functors.)

My problem is that I don't know how to prove it. For what this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611514/394668) says, there are really not a lot places to learn about the issue of composing morphisms of ringed spaces. The only place I've found that mentions the exact issue I'm asking about is EGA 0, 3.5.5 ([here](https://labs.thosgood.com/ega/ega0-auto.pdf) a version in English):

[image]

The critical expression in which it is proven the fact about I'm asking for is squared in red. The thing is that I don't understand where the “then we have immediately that $w^\sharp$ is the composite morphism” comes from.

Some notes on what is Grothendieck considering there: Instead of ringed spaces, he considers general “sheafed spaces” and morphisms of “sheafed spaces,” which are just a generalization to the case of ringed spaces. A “sheafed space” is a pair $(X,\mathscr{F})$, where $X$ is a topological space and $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$ valued on some category $\mathsf{C}$, and the definition of a morphism between sheafed spaces is, *mutatis mutandis*, the same as the definition we have wrote here for ringed spaces. The category of “sheafed spaces” is also addressed in EGA 0, 3.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the adjunction isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(f^{-1} {-}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, f_* {-})$, apply naturality to the morphism $(\varphi^{\sharp}, \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{O}_X})$ and the fact that $\psi^\sharp \mapsto \psi^\flat$ to get that $\psi^\sharp \circ f^{-1} \varphi^\sharp \mapsto \psi^\flat \circ \varphi^\sharp$.  Likewise, in the adjunction isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(g^{-1} {-}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, g_* {-})$, apply naturality to the morphism $(\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{O}_Z}, \psi^\flat)$ and the fact that $\varphi^\sharp \mapsto \varphi^\flat$ to see that $\psi^\flat \circ \varphi^\sharp \mapsto g_* \psi^\flat \circ \varphi^\flat$.

It now remains to verify that the adjunction $\operatorname{Hom}((g\circ f)^{-1} {-}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, (g\circ f)_* {-})$ agrees exactly with the composition of the adjunctions for $g$ and $f$, i.e. that it is equal to the composition $$\operatorname{Hom}((g\circ f)^{-1} {-}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(f^{-1} g^{-1} {-}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(g^{-1} {-}, f_* {-}) \simeq \\
\operatorname{Hom}({-}, g_* f_* {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}({-}, (g\circ f)_* {-}).$$
However, on deeper inspection, recall that most likely, the way we *defined* the canonical isomorphism $(g\circ f)^{-1} \mathcal{F} \simeq f^{-1} g^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ is very closely related to applying the Yoneda lemma to the isomorphism of functors
$$\operatorname{Hom}((g\circ f)^{-1} \mathcal{F}, {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, (g\circ f)_* {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{F}, g_* f_* {-}) \simeq \\
\operatorname{Hom}(g^{-1} \mathcal{F}, f_* {-}) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(f^{-1} g^{-1} \mathcal{F}, {-}).$$
So in a sense, the actual situation is inverted from the desired statement: we chose the canonical isomorphism $(g\circ f)^{-1} \simeq f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ exactly in such a way that the adjunction between $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ and $(g\circ f)_*$ would agree with the composition of the adjunctions between $g^{-1}$ and $g_*$, respectively $f^{-1}$ and $f_*$.